# Database files and the system swap space on the same disk?

Tags: mysql, performance, database, swap, swapping

Why is it problematic to configure the database files and the system swap space on the same disk? What can happen?

Comment: The system could start swapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the system starts swapping, the increased disk load will bring down database performance even further. Anyway, an heavy-swapping system will be nearly unusable, even when putting swap on dedicated disk.

Bottom line: be sure your RAM is enough for your workload, rather than worrying about swapping destination.